# Identifier removed at shmat()

Tags: c, shared-memory, identifier

it is part of my code.
When run it, there was an error. It is "identifier removed". I am adding my output.

```
#define SEMKEYPATH "/dev/null"

typedef struct myStruct3 {
struct myStruct3* next=NULL;
}mainList;

mainList* shared;

int main(){

    key_t KEYSHM=ftok(SEMKEYPATH,17);
    int cid;

    if(cid=shmget(KEYSHM, sizeof(mainList), IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0) perror("1----:"); 

    if((shared=(mainList*)shmat(cid,NULL,0))==(mainList*) -1) perror("2----:");

    printf("memory: %d\n",cid);
}
```

''' output,

```
2--- Identifier removed
memory: 0
```

there was no output about perror 1'''

Comment: You use extra parentheses around the assignment to `shared` in your second condition... Why do you have that? Think about that a little while, and take a closer look at the first condition again.

Comment: ...which lacks those parentheses, and so the order of evaluation is different... `shmget(...) < 0` is evaluated *before* the assignment to `cid` and so it is the *result of the comparison* that is assigned to `cid`, *not* the value returned by `shmget`.